Kiddush levana vs women
There seems to be a connection between the first sin related to Chava and Kiddush Levana. Perhaps this comnection is the reason Ashkenazi women avoid saying Kiddush Levana. I appreciate anything to help me learn about the reasoning and connection.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

can you clarify why you think there is a connection between chava and kiddush levana? Did you learn it somewhere?

possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/48539/759 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/82584/759

The Shela says women shouldn't say Kiddush Levana since Chava caused the moon to shrink. This is what you're referring to?

Robev: did Chava caused the moon to shrink? Or it was moon that brought this to itself? In the midrash I heard, the moon complained about being similar as Sun. There were nothing mentioned about Chaya. Can you elaborate pl
