# Why is Rosh Chodesh festive?

Tags: taamei-mitzvot-reasons, rosh-chodesh-new-month, simchah-joy-happiness

There are both mitzvos and customs that seem to elevate the status of Rosh Chodesh and give it a holiday-like status. Why?

Shabbos and holidays have explicit reasons for being festive. But what is the cause for celebration just because a new month is starting?

Comment: Zeman Kapara...

Comment: It was probably already considered festive when the Torah was given for paganish reasons. And as time went on its significance diminished to the point we don't even know why it was so special to people in Tanakh.

Comment: @GershonGold OK, is there an explanation for why it is a zman kapparah?

Comment: Gemara somewhere regarding Hashem requesting Mechila from the moon

Comment: Chullin 60b per  [this answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14610/forgiveness-on-rosh-chodesh), although it doesn't totally explain the festivity IMO.

Comment: It is called Zeman kappara because one brings a sin offering on it, which many interpret to mean its like a mini yom kippur

Comment: maybe some kind of shehichiyanu

Comment: It reminds us that just like the moon is renewed after disappearing, so will our exile eventually end. This is a comforting thought.

Comment: To start, view beginning of book of Shmu'el as well as a few places within it. IIRC, Chana's husband made a celebration on Rosh Hodesh; so did King Saul (see haftara *Machar Chodesh*). If I have the chance, I'll research some commentaries on it and post, later. I assume that since Rosh Hodesh is both the 1st communal mitzvah given to us as a nation, and it is the "foundation" of the Jewish people's "time management" system as well as the foundation of all other holidays - all these would make it cause for celebration, I think!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the Oruch HaShulchan in [סימן תיט - דין סעודת ראש חודש](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01582.html#HtmpReportNum0328_L2) who mentions various reasons why Rosh Chodesh is considered festive:

1. Rosh Chodesh is mentioned in the  Torah ([Bemidbar 10](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t0410.htm):10) as one of times we festively blow the Shofar when bringing Korbanot: וּבְיוֹם שִׂמְחַתְכֶם וּבְמוֹעֲדֵיכֶם, וּבְרָאשֵׁי חָדְשֵׁיכֶם--וּתְקַעְתֶּם בַּחֲצֹצְרֹת עַל עֹלֹתֵיכֶם, וְעַל זִבְחֵי שַׁלְמֵיכֶם
2. It's mentioned in Nach also bundled with Shabbat and/or Chag.
3. In Navi we see that they made festive meals on Rosh Chodesh.
4. The festivities are in honour of the  atonement that Rosh Chodesh brings.
5. Possibly also in commemoration of the festive meals served to the new-moon-sighting witnesses to ensure they came back monthly.

> **א** כתב הטור: 
>   ''מצוה להרבות בסעודת ראש חודש. דגרסינן במגילה פרק ראשון (בירושלמי) במשנה דמקדימין ולא מאחרין: אבל סעודת פורים וסעודת ראש חודש – מאחרין ולא מקדימין. כלומר: כשנפל ראש חודש בשבת, דבלאו הכי יש סעודת שבת – עושין סעודת ראש חודש ביום ראשון, כפורים שחל בשבת. ומדמדמה לפורים – שמע מינה שהוא חיוב. 
>   ועוד: דאיתקש ל''מועד'' בקרא ד''וביום שמחתכם''. וכתיב גבי דוד: ''כי זבח משפחה לנו'', וראש חודש היה, דכתיב ''ויהי ממחרת החדש השני''. ובפסיקתא איתא: כל מזונותיו של אדם קצובים לו מראש השנה, לבד מה שמוציא בהוצאות שבתות, וימים טובים, וראש חודש, וחולו של מועד, ומה שהתנוקות מוליכין לבית רבן. אם מוסיף – מוסיפין לו וכו''', עד כאן לשון הטור.‏ 
>   **ב** וגם ברוקח (סימן רכח) כתב כן. והביא עוד מקרא ד''והיה מדי חדש בחדשו, ומדי שבת בשבתו'', ומקרא ד''מדוע את הולכת אליו היום, לא חדש ולא שבת'', עיין שם.‏ 
>   וכן הכלבו כתב דהסעודה היא מפני כבוד היום, שהוא כפרה לישראל וכו', זכר לסעודה שעושין לעידי הלבנה בזמן המקדש וכו'. עד כאן לשונו. ונראה דכונתו לסעודה שהיו עושין בעיבור החודש, כדאיתא בירושלמי. וכן נראה מש''ס דילן בסנהדרין, לענין בן סורר ומורה, דאם אכל בעיבור החודש – אינו נעשה בן סורר ומורה (ע א). ‏

Comment: Sources would be good. There is the reference to Saul's "Rosh Chodesh" event at which David was missing and also Elisha saying to the woman "why do you come, it is not Shabbat or Rosh Chodesh"

Comment: +1 for good, short answer. I alluded to those 2 items that @Cashcow mentions. in my previous comment, as those seemed most obvious to me. The idea about the meal given to the witnesses is mentioned in Talmud Rosh Hashanna. I understood, though, that the food was there before *Kiddush Hachodesh*, not afterwards. Did I misunderstand that idea?

Comment: @cas the op did source his answer

Comment: @CashCow - all that is in the Hebrew "source" summarized as "In Navi we see that they made festive meals on Rosh Chodesh."